# Регулярные выражения C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, asp.net-mvc

В проекте ASP.NET MVC5 требуется запретить начинать тайтл с более чем одной Заглавной буквы.
Делаю так:

```
[RegularExpression("^[А-Я]{2,}", ErrorMessage = "Заголовок не может начинаться с более чем одной заглавной")]
```

но результат отличается от ожидаемого. Как исправить регулярку?

Comment: А каков результат с такой регуляркой?

Comment: Вы почему-то считаете, что `[А-Я]` представляет собой набор всех заглавных букв русского алфавита. Это не так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В атрибуте надо указывать регулярку, которой должно **соответствовать** корректное значение. Поэтому регулярка должна быть такой:

```
^(?![A-ZА-ЯЁ]{2,})
```